# Regex to replace commas between a positive number and negative number

Tags: javascript

```
        global=global.toString().replace(/(\d+),,,(?=\d)/g, '$1&#44;.');
```

1. I am replacing the commas here. I need to replace the commas in between a positive and the second a negative number.
2. I am replacing the commas here. I need to replace the commas in between a positive and the second a positive or negative number.

How do I do both of these?

Comment: Do you have any sample?

Comment: just need some help with the regex code
the global is an array and can be anything... like a string:  1,-1 or 1,1 or -1,-1

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
const global = '1,-1,2,4,-2';
global.replace(/(-?\d+),(?=-?\d+)/g, '$1&#44;.');
```

will output

```
'1&#44;.-1&#44;.2&#44;.4&#44;.-2'
```

So, you just need to add `-?` in your expression to indicate it is possible to be positive or negative.